# How to find the printer url on linux (debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, printing, printer

There was a problem during installing some packages for the printer server on debian.

I used the commands:

```
apt-get install task-print-server

apt-get install cups
```

And I got following errors:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y / n] j
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.35) ...
Groupadd: Error writing changes to / etc / group
Addgroup: / usr / sbin / groupadd -g 122 ssl-cert returned error code 10. > Programs.
Dpkg: Error processing package ssl-cert (--configure):
Subprocess installed post-installation script returned the error value of 1
Dpkg: Dependency problems prevent configuration of cups daemon:
Cups-daemon depends on ssl-cert (> = 1.0.11); but:
 Package ssl-cert is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Error processing the package cups-daemon (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
Cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (> = 1.7.5-11 + deb8u1); but:
 Package cups-daemon is not yet configured.

Dpkg: Error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Set up cups-client (1.7.5-11 + deb8u1) ...
Group "lpadmin" (GID 122) ...
Groupadd: Error writing changes to / etc / group
Addgroup: / usr / sbin / groupadd -g 122 lpadmin returned error code 10.  > > Programs.
Dpkg: Error processing package cups-client (--configure):
 Subprocess installed post-installation script returned the error value of 1
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
Cups depends on cups-core-drivers (> = 1.7.5-11 + deb8u1); but:
 Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
Cups depends on cups-daemon (> = 1.7.5-11 + deb8u1); but:
 Package cups-daemon is not yet configured.
Cups depends on cups-client (> = 1.7.5-11 + deb8u1); but:
 Package cups-client is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Error processing the package cups (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent printer-driver-hpcups configuration:
Printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups (> = 1.4.0) Cupsddk; but:
 Package cups is not configured yet.
 Package cupsddk is not installed.
Printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups; but:
 Package cups is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Error processing package printer-driver-hpcups (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent hplip configuration:
Hplip depends on printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.14.6-1 + deb8u1); but:
 Package printer-driver-hpcups is not configured yet.
Hplip depends on cups (> = 1.1.20); but:
 Package cups is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Error processing package hplip (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent printer-driver-postscript-hp 
configuration:
Printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on hplip (> = 3.14.6-1 + deb8u1); but:
 Package hplip is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Error processing package printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent printer-driver-goodprint configuration:
Printer-driver-goodprint depends on cups (> = 1.3.0); but:
 Package cups is not configured yet.
Printer-driver-goodprint depends on cups-client (> = 1.3.0); but:
 Package cups-client is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Failed to edit package-printer-driver-goodprint (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent printer-driver-splix configuration:
Printer-driver-splix depends on cups (> = 1.5.0-3 ~); but:
 Package cups is not configured yet.
Printer-driver-splix depends on cups-client; but:
 Package cups-client is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Failed to edit package-printer-driver-splix (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-bsd:
Cups-bsd depends on cups-client (= 1.7.5-11 + deb8u1); but:
 Package cups-client is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of task-print-server:
Task-print-server depends on cups; but:
 Package cups is not configured yet.
Task-print-server depends on cups-client; but:
 Package cups-client is not configured yet.
Task-print-server depends on cups-bsd; but:
 Package cups-bsd is not configured yet.

Dpkg: Failed to edit package task-print-server (--configure):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Errors occurred while editing: ssl-cert
cups-daemon
cups-core-drivers
cups-client
cups
printer-driver-hpcups
hplip
printer-driver-postscript-hp
printer-driver-gutenprint
printer-driver-splix
cups-bsd
task-print-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know if this caused to not find the printer automatically. At least I could get the cups server running and tried to add a new printer, however it asks me for an url of the printer. I just typed ipp:// and I could follow other steps to install the right printer driver too. But when I want to print the system says url missing or wrong.

Is there a way to find this url ?

Ouput of stat:

```
root@debian:/# stat /etc/group
Datei: „/etc/group“
Size: 890 Blocks: 8 EA Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 801h / 2049d Inode: 263431 Shortcuts: 1
Access: (0644 / -rw -r - r--) Uid: (0 / root) Gid: (0 / root)
Access: 2017-04-30 17: 38: 18.204676461 +0200
Modified: 2016-09-23 14: 51: 00.519083038 +0200
Changed: 2016-09-23 14: 51: 00.519083038 +0200
Birth: -

Root @ debian: / # stat / etc / passwd
File: "/ etc / passwd"
Size: 2119 Blocks: 8 EA Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 801h / 2049d Inode: 263492 Shortcuts: 1
Access: (0644 / -rw -r - r--) Uid: (0 / root) Gid: (0 / root)
Access: 2017-05-01 01: 17: 01.237979036 +0200
Modified: 2017-04-03 00: 27: 01.880558770 +0200
Changed: 2017-04-03 00: 27: 01.880558770 +0200
Birth: -
```

Output of lsattr:

```
root@debian:/# lsattr /etc/passwd
-------------e-- /etc/passwd

root@debian:/# lsattr /etc/group
-------------e-- /etc/group
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to find your printer automatically? How is the printer connected to your PC? What make and model (please be precise) is the printer?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the printer is connected via usb2.0 highspeed, it is an Epson Stylus SX200, on a vm with Debian 3.16.0-4-686-pae.

Comment: Ah, alright. So it should indeed be detected automatically. I don’t have a Linux-compatible printer available, so I cannot provide instructions on that. Could you perhaps clarify what exactly went wrong when you installed CUPS? How did you install it? The exact command may still be available in `history`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers, I updated my question, with the requested infos.

Comment: Hm. Please provide the output of `stat /etc/passwd /etc/group` and `lsattr /etc/passwd /etc/group`. Verify that whatever partition `/etc` is on isn’t mounted read-only. Do you have AppArmor, SELinux or something similar active? Are any other security measures in place that would prevent `useradd` or `groupapp` from working?

Comment: No I don't have neither AppArmor or SELinux. Just FireJail, ClamAV, Privoxy. For the output see the updated question.

Comment: can you confirm you had administrative privileges at the time you executed the apt-get commands?

Comment: Yes I used "su" to get administrativ privileges.